Do I really need to waterproof my interior basement wall before insulating?
I am looking to insulate the basement walls of my detached house in Ottawa, Canada (cold climate).  Currently, the walls are unfinished poured concrete and losing a lot of heat.  The basement is fully below grade.
After consulting some resources, my plan is this:

Frame the walls with 2x4 (pressure treated bottom plate with a strip of vapour barrier under the bottom plate), leaving a small air gap behind the wall
Insulate the framing cavity with R14 fiberglass batts (as well as the headers)
Vapour barrier over the exposed fibrrglass.

I’ve seen some people say you need to install Typar or Tyvek on the exposed concrete wall before framing, supposedly to prevent moisture from coming through the concrete wall and wetting the fiberglass insulation.
Here’s my situation though; I recently had a large part of the (previously leaky) foundation wall repaired and waterproofed. I had horizontal cracks patched, waterproofing membrane and foam board installed on the outside wall below grade, as well as new weeping tile.  Since then, my basement has been fully dry.
Seeing as the outside of my house has already been properly waterproofed, do I really need the layer of house wrap inside?

Firstly, be aware of the different roles of the various barriers installed in modern homes to avoid confusion. An exterior membrane is to block liquid water. House wrap does this also. Interior barriers block vapor, which is usually coming from inside the home, so it doesn't accumulate and condense inside the insulation. Your exterior membrane does nothing to address that. These are different concerns with different solutions, and they don't overlap in function.
This is a tricky situation best addressed on a case-by-case basis. I've owned a similar home. Here's my advice.

House wrap inside the foundation is pointless. It's sole purpose is to block liquid water (and airflow, but that's not an issue here). It doesn't block vapor, which is what accumulates in insulation where the dew point occurs.

Vapor barrier is intended to prevent moisture from migrating outward in most cases. You'd install it as you describe.

However, if there's any chance you'll have moisture coming through the foundation, you may opt to forego the vapor barrier, allowing moisture to pass freely and dry out, rather than accumulating in the insulation and causing mold.


I suggest that you think carefully about how vapor will move in your home. Disregard your outside waterproofing completely, as it's completely irrelevant. Consider asking neighbors what has worked for them.
